# Sending email attachment python

Tags: python, email, indentation

> I am trying to send an email through python, but I am getting
>       an unexpected unindent error on msg.addpayload(part). I am getting
>       the error on the same msg.attach(part) when I copy + paste other
>       peoples code as well.

```
def sendemail(logfile, password='somepassword'):
    # Initialize email sender/receiver/servers 
    email_subject = logfile 
    email_receiver = 'email@gmail.com' 
    email_sender = 'someemail@gmail.com'
    gmail_smtp = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    gmail_smtp_port = 587
    text_subtype = 'plain'
    filepath = os.path.abspath(logfile)

    # Create the message 
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_sender
    msg['To'] = email_receiver
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = str(email_subject)

    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload( open(logfile, 'rb').read() )
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filepath)
    # Attach file to message

    msg.add_payload(part)

    # try:
    server_gmail = smtplib.SMTP(gmail_smtp, gmail_smtp_port)
        # Identify self to gmail server 
    server_gmail.ehlo()
        # Put SMTP connection in TLS mode and call ehlo again 
    server_gmail.starttls() 
    #server_gmail.ehlo()
        # Login to service 
    server_gmail.login(email_sender,password)
        # Send email 
    server_gmail.sendmail(email_sender,email_receiver,msg.as_string())
        # Close connection 
    server_gmail.close() 
    print("mail sent")
    # except:
    #   print("failed to send mail")
sendemail('logtest.csv', 'somepassword')
```

Comment: [Code indentation is significant in Python](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. This confuses Python.

[image]

Only use one or the other, not both. Spaces is preferable.